# add button choose language android app

Tags: android, eclipse, button, multilingual

Hello I am looking to add two button on main layout Ar + En
to open choose the language of the app between values-ar + values-en

can anybody help me on that ???
I am using eclipse to build my apps

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) to give an option for language selection and on `onItemSelected` event you can dynamically change the current default language of your application, e.g:

```
languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    Locale l = null;        
    if(arabic) {
        l = new Locale("en_US");
    } else if(english) {
        l = new Locale("ar_SA");
    }

    Locale.setDefault(l);
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.locale = locale;
    yourActivity.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas , can you show full way to do please on layout can you contact me on helpline@hotmail.co.uk